# Don't have right permission to extract file in /opt folder

Tags: permissions, archive, sqldeveloper

I am trying to install `sqldeveloper`. I tried to extract the zip file in `/opt` but it shows this error:

```
you don't have the right permission to extract archives in the folder "opt".
```

I tried changing the permissions using  `chmod 777/opt-R` but that also didn't work.

Please suggest what to do.

Comment: Please don't `chmod` system directories to carry out operations like this. If you do need to use `chmod`, mode 777 is almost never the one you want, and the `-R` flag is rarely useful (and often harmful)

Comment: Permission mode 777 is convenient, but not as safe as modes that are more restrictive.

Answer (score 2):

**`sudo` privileges are required to make changes in `/opt` directory.**

Use this command to extract `file.zip` in /opt.

```
sudo unzip file.zip -d /opt
```