# Adding execute permission in opt folder

Tags: command-line, permissions

I am trying to install oracle database in `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`.
I had unzipped the oracle database file in opt folder,but now when I am trying to give execute right to the sqldeveloper file using `chmod +x sqldeveloper.sh`, it's throwing this error:

```
chmod: changing permissions of 'sqldeveloper.sh': Operation not permitted
```

Comment: You just asked something similar: https://askubuntu.com/questions/971135/dont-have-right-permission-to-extract-file-in-opt-folder

Comment: You need to use `sudo` when trying to do anything in root privileged directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not the owner of a file you can't modify its permission bits. Well, with [richacls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richacls) you can do that, but you are not going to find it in a basic Ubuntu installation

The root user can do that. There are many ways to become root user in GNU/Linux. The recommended way to do this in Ubuntu is by using `sudo`

```
sudo chmod +x /opt/sqldeveloper.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

The command to use is:

```
sudo chmod +x /opt/sqldeveloper.sh
```